# i need some basic godot enemy movement script in godot 4.0 or a way to make the enemy movement in godot 4.0

Tags: character-encoding, godot, gdscript

All I need is an enemy movement script or some instructions on how to make it.
Your efforts to help me will be greatly appreciated.

Personal Experience: I'm kind of still new but are gaining knowledge pretty quickly with YouTube tutorials (which I can't find on this topic)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to use would be a `CharacterBody`. I am going to assume you are doing this in 2D so we will be using a `CharacterBody2D` for this.
Steps to making basic enemy movement:

1. First thing you want to do is create a variable to define the speed at which an enemy moves. Example: `var speed = 10`
2. Next you want to create 4 functions for the 4 movement directions.

Example:

```
func move_up():
func move_down():
func move_left():
func move_right():
```

3. Next we want to make each function move the enemy in a different direction. To do this we are going to use the CharacterBody's built in `velocity` variable. To move up and down we have to move along the y-axis. Lets turn this into functions:

   ```
   func move_up():
       velocity.y = -speed

   func move_down():
       velocity.y = speed
   ```

   Now we have to make the other 2 functions. To move left and right we have to move along the x-axis. Here are the functions for that:

   ```
   func move_left():
       velocity.x = -speed

   func move_right():
       velocity.x = speed
   ```
4. Now that we have those functions made, we need to call them to make the enemy move:

   ```
   func _physics_process(delta):
       move_down()
   ```

   The enemy won't move yet because we need to add the move_and_slide() function at the after changing the velocity to actually move the CharacterBody.

   ```
   func _physics_process(delta):
       move_down()
   ```

This is the final code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D
var speed = 10

func move_up():
    velocity.y = -10

func move_down():
    velocity.y = 10

func move_left():
    velocity.x = -10

func move_right():
    velocity.x = 10

func _physics_process(delta):
    move_down()
    move_and_slide()
```